# how can we serialize singleton ? I guess we cannot

Tags: java

I found many threads running in stackoverflow.com for making SingleTon object serializable.
And also experts are providing way to serialize Singleton object.

In my opinion, we cannot Serialize singleton object even if we implement Serializable interface, 
 because SingleTon reference variable is static in the same class. 
And Serialization api says that we cannot serialize or write static-reference's state in the file.
And also we cannot save the state of transient variable.
While serialization process (actual writing process) static and transient variables are ignored.
Please give your valuable inputs if I misunderstood. If I misunderstood, can anybody help to serialize Singleton object with code example?

Comment: Did you try to implement a Singleton which implements Serializable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, static references aren't seralized.  that doesn't mean you couldn't take the value of a static reference (the singleton instance) and choose to serialize it.

Comment: Well, in that case, we can save values without having Serializable interface implemented on singleton class.  Because every complex object (for example singleton class's object) ends up with primitive type wrapper object like Integer, Long, Double, String and all those are implemented with Serializable interface so that we can serialize values inside singleton object. What I understood from your comment is that we cannot serialize Singleton as a object. Instead we have to retrieve values from it and serialize it in the file

Comment: @AmitG - no, that's not what i said at all.  you can certainly serialize a singleton as an object.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are mixing up the way a singleton is implemented and the way the objects are serialized.

While the static field which is often used to implement singletons indeed would not be serialized as part of serializing an instance, the instance itself can definitely be serialized. All you'd need to do is to set its deserialized version back into the static field, which you would need to do manually in your code.

P.S. Please note that I'm not saying that serializing (or even implementing) a singleton is necessarily a good idea, all I'm saying is that it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Singletons can be serialized and here is the code on how to do it:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class MySingleton implements Serializable {

    private MySingleton(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private static MySingleton mySingleton;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance(String name) {
        if(mySingleton == null) {
            System.out.println("in if...");
            mySingleton = new MySingleton(name);
        }

        return mySingleton;
    }
}
```

and here is "main" method which gets the instance of the Singleton class above,  serializes and de-serializes it:

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {

        MySingleton m = MySingleton.getInstance("Akshay");

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D://temp.ser"));
            oos.writeObject(m);

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("D://temp.ser"));
            MySingleton m2 = (MySingleton) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(m2.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and output is:-

> in if...
>
> Akshay

Thanks.

Comment: But if you compare hashcodes of objects before and after serailization, they are different. Means two new instances get created for a Singleton class! To avoid this use readResolve method in your Singleton class like shown here: `protected Object readResolve() {
        return getInstance(name);
    }`

Comment: Refer below link to know more about readResolve method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#5903